# javac behavior change in JDK 7 regarding private member access

Tags: java, javac, java-7, private-members

This code compiles OK using javac JDK version 1.6.0_33-b03-424, but doesn't compile using javac JDK version 1.7.0_06.

```
public class Test {
    private final int i = 0;

    void test(Object o) {
        if (getClass().isInstance(o)) {
            System.out.println(getClass().cast(o).i);
        }
    }
}
```

javac output is:

```
Test.java:6: error: i in Test is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
        System.out.println(getClass().cast(o).i);
                                             ^
1 error
```

Changing the code to store the result of `getClass.cast()` in a temporary variable allows the program to compile without error.

This is easy to work around, but I can't find any rationale for this change in the JLS 7, or any mention of a change like this in the JDK 7 release notes.  There is a mention of an access change regarding private members of type parameters to a generic, but that doesn't apply here.

Is this a regression in javac? Is it now enforcing a restriction that it wasn't enforcing before?

Comment: Sure looks like a regression, I can't see the JDK7 error message making sense in any way.

Comment: The Eclipse compiler (JDT 3.7.2) is also unable to compile this... and yet gives the rather quizzical quick fix "replace i with i"

Comment: This code compiles fine for me on a Mac, running jdk 1.7.0_05-b05, hard to believe they introduced this in _06, but I will upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: NetBeans with Java 6 shows the same error in the code editor but if I ignore the error it does allow me to compile (and even run) the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm puzzled by this and the only explanation I can adventure is the conjunction of two things.

1_ [`getClass()` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) say the following:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is
>   called.

2_ One of the [incompatibilities introduced in Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#behavioral) is **Compiler No Longer Allows Access to Private Members of Type Variables**.

So, the compiler is unsure it the cast is made to the base class or a subclass and it blocks accesing a private member, since if the cast were to be assigned to a subclass it would be illegal even if defined in the original parent class, as shown in the following example:

```
class BaseTest {
    private final int i = 1;

    void test(Object o) {
        if (getClass().isInstance(o)) {                
            TestAccess to = TestAccess.class.cast(o);
            //System.out.println(to.i);  // ERROR: i has private access in BaseTest
        }
    }
}

class TestAccess extends BaseTest{}
```

So, I guess it's one more of Java quirks due to rules that make more sense in more complex examples.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that `X.getClass()` returned `Class<X>` but it makes sense that it doesn't. Changing the code to explicitly cast the result of getClass() also fixes the problem, which seems to confirm this explanation. It's a bit odd that the error messages are completely different though.

Comment: In this case class Test is not final, and method test() is not private.  So a subclass could call Test::test and then getClass() would return the class object of the subclass.  And then, from an instance cast to that subclass, you couldn't access the private field I.